# issue with setting up vim errorformat

Tags: vim, errorformat

My compiler and lint tools put out errors in two different formats. I decided to incrementally setup my errorformat, first for lint and then add a pattern for a compiler.

Here is the lint output line I'm trying to match to

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\user\Projects\MyProject\trunk\src\myfile.c",126  Info 754: local structure member 'myStructMember' (line 126, file C:\Documents and Settings\user\Projects\MyProject\trunk\src\myfile.c) not referenced
```

My first attempt was

```
set errorformat=\"%f\"\\,%l\ \ %t%s
```

And it worked.

Then I tried to set it up as follows

```
set errorformat=\"%f\"\\,%l\ \ %t\ %s
```

And it stopped working.

Does anybody know what is the issue?
I did read through the documentation but it didn't help.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So it's the `Info 754` which matched correctly with no space between, but does not match when there's a space between?

Comment: I figured out the issue. %t matches only the first character. So if %t\ %s matches the first character of the error type then space and then the string. To make it work I had to change it to %t%*\w%*\s%s

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
" Match the filename and line number
let &errorformat = '"%f"\,%l'

" Match white space, first character of error type, the rest of the characters
" of the error type, and white space again.
let &errorformat .= '%*\s%t%*\w%*\s'

"Match error number, whitespace and error message.
let &errorformat .= '%n:%*\s%m'
```